# É possível selecionar períodos de uma tabela em um select sem subquery?

Tags: sql, pl-sql, oracle10g

Saudações,

gostaria de saber se é possível selecionar um período de uma tabela sem usar uma subquery conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
Select Usuario, Divida.Janeiro , Divida.Fevereiro, Divida.Marco ... from Usuarios a
left join VW_Dividas_Por_Mes b on a.cod_user = b.cod_user
```

Neste caso eu tenho uma view que traz resultados por data `where dt_divida between '01/01/2020' and '31/01/2020'` mas eu queria exibir apenas um mês a mês no select, sem ter que realizar uma subquery ou especificar a data no join.

Isso é possível?

Comment: Como é a "view" ? Ela coluna ?

Comment: A view seria: cod_user, dt_divida, valor

Comment: Vc poderia fazer um case , algo como sum(case when to_char(dt_divida,'yyyymm') = '202001' then valor else 0 end) ..., mas creio que o custo será pior.